# Hashmap keySet() returns the value instead of the key

Tags: java, hashmap, keyset

Here is my method.In the hashmap I have pairs of Country - Capital(Russia - Moscow) for Europe.However, it keeps returning me the value(the capital) instead of the key(the country).I tested my hashmap and it is in the correct order.

```
Map<String, String> europe1 = new HashMap<String, String>()

public String randomCountry(Map theMap)
{
  Random generator = new Random();
  List<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>(theMap.keySet());
  String randomKey = keys.get(generator.nextInt(keys.size()));
  Object theKeyValue = (String )theMap.get(randomKey);

  System.out.println(theKeyValue);
  return (String) theKeyValue;  
}
```

If I do this:

```
for ( String key : europe1.keySet() )
 { System.out.println( key ); }
```

I get my countries printed.

Any ideas why my method does not work as expected?

Comment: `Object theKeyValue = (String )theMap.get(randomKey);`... since you're already casting to String, why don't you just store the result in a String instead of Object, which requires yet another cast?...

Comment: `String theKeyValue = (String) theMap.get(randomKey);`
 
`return theKeyValue;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are fetching the value here :

```
Object theKeyValue = (String )theMap.get(randomKey);
```

If you want `randomCountry` to return the key, you should return `randomKey` instead of `theKeyValue`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Object theKeyValue = (String )theMap.get(randomKey);
```

you can return randomKey.

Please find HashMap documentation link for more details regarding keySet() : to return only Key and entrySet() : to return key value pair.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html